# juliaでツリーの葉を巡回するイテレータを実装したい

Tags: julia

juliaでツリーの葉を巡回するイテレータを実装したいです。
ツリーのノードは複数種類あると思ってください。
Rubyで書くと以下のような感じです。
juliaではどのように実装すればいいでしょうか？

```rb
class MyTree_A
    attr_accessor :data
    
    def initialize
        @data=[]
    end
    
    def each_leaf
        @data.each{|item|
            if item.respond_to?(:each_leaf)
            then
                item.each_leaf{|item2| yield(item2)}
            else
                yield(item)
            end
        }
    end
    
    def push(item)
        @data.push(item)
    end
    
end

class MyTree_B
    attr_accessor :data
    
    def initialize
        @data=[]
    end
    
    def each_leaf
        @data.each{|item|
            if item.respond_to?(:each_leaf)
            then
                item.each_leaf{|item2| yield(item2)}
            else
                yield(item)
            end
        }
    end
    
    def push(item)
        @data.push(item)
    end
    
end



root_node=MyTree_A.new
child_node1=MyTree_A.new
child_node2=MyTree_B.new
child_node3=MyTree_A.new
child_node1_1=MyTree_B.new
child_node1_2=MyTree_B.new
child_node1_3=MyTree_A.new

child_node1_1.push("1_1_1")
child_node1_1.push("1_1_2")
child_node1_1.push("1_1_3")

child_node1_2.push("1_2_1")
child_node1_2.push("1_2_2")

child_node1_3.push("1_3_1")

child_node2.push("2_1")
child_node2.push("2_2")
child_node2.push("2_3")

child_node3.push("3_1")

child_node1.push(child_node1_1)
child_node1.push(child_node1_2)
child_node1.push(child_node1_3)

root_node.push(child_node1)
root_node.push(child_node2)
root_node.push(child_node3)

root_node.each_leaf{|item| print("#{item}\n")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julia では Channel 型は Iterable としても機能しますので、それを利用します。

```
struct MyTree
    data::Vector{}
    MyTree() = new(Any[])
end

function each_leaf(tree::MyTree)
    ch = Channel()
    function _each_leaf(tree::MyTree, depth = 1)
        for tr in tree.data
            if applicable(each_leaf, tr)
                _each_leaf(tr, depth+1)
            else
                put!(ch, tr)
            end
        end
        if depth == 1
            close(ch)
        end
    end

    @async _each_leaf(tree)
    ch
end

function push(tree::MyTree, items...)
    push!(tree.data, items...)
end

#
root_node = MyTree()
child_node1 = MyTree()
child_node2 = MyTree()
child_node3 = MyTree()
child_node1_1 = MyTree()
child_node1_2 = MyTree()
child_node1_3 = MyTree()

push(child_node1_1, "1_1_1", "1_1_2", "1_1_3")
push(child_node1_2, "1_2_1", "1_2_2")
push(child_node1_3, "1_3_1")
push(child_node2, "2_1", "2_2", "2_3")
push(child_node3, "3_1")
push(child_node1, child_node1_1, child_node1_2, child_node1_3)
push(root_node, child_node1, child_node2, child_node3)

foreach(println, each_leaf(root_node))
# foreach(leaf -> println(leaf), each_leaf(root_node))

# 1_1_1
# 1_1_2
# 1_1_3
# 1_2_1
# 1_2_2
# 1_3_1
# 2_1
# 2_2
# 2_3
# 3_1
```

Comment: ちなみにですが、木の深さが1深くなる度に新しいチャンネルを開くのはマズイのでしょうか？

Comment: 新しいチャネルを開く場合は、それらを全て `each_leaf` 関数の呼び出し元に返す(return)ことになります。そのため、読み出し側では複数のチャネルから読み出すことになりますので、処理としては煩雑になるかと思います。